# Swift How to parse string array using Codable Protocol

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

This is my "wrapper" class:

```
class QuestionResult: Codable {

    var title: String?
    var questions: [Question]?
}
```

Question class:

```
class Question: Codable{

    var question_id: Int?
    var question_type: String?
    var question: String?
    var answers: [String]?   
}
```

and this is the relative JSON:

```
{
   "title":"sondaggio di test",
   "start_message":"<p>sodaggio di prova</p>\r\n",
   "end_message":"<p>fine sondaggio di test</p>\r\n",
   "start_date":"2020-05-01",
   "end_date":"2020-05-22",
   "voted":false,
   "questions":[
      {
         "question_id":418,
         "question_type":"number",
         "question":"domanda test 1"
      },
      {
         "question_id":419,
         "question_type":"checkbox",
         "question":"domanda test 2",
         "answers":[
            "risp1",
            "risp2",
            "risp3",
            "risp4",
            "risp5"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, all properties has been parsed correctly except for the "answers" properties that return nil.
How can I parse an array of strings using Codable protocol?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. The first question doesn't have an `answers`, so it should be nil, but the second one does, and when I test your code it works fine for `questions.questions![1].answers!`. Can you show the actual test code you're using and the result you're seeing? Are you possibly looking at `questions[0]` (which should return nil for answers?)

Comment: (For example: https://gist.github.com/rnapier/cba3d4e5ae0374e7e76ba0f10c83200a.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the model:

```
struct QuestionResult: Codable {
    let title, startMessage, endMessage, startDate: String
    let endDate: String
    let voted: Bool
    let questions: [Question]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case startMessage = "start_message"
        case endMessage = "end_message"
        case startDate = "start_date"
        case endDate = "end_date"
        case voted, questions
    }
}

struct Question: Codable {
    let questionID: Int
    let questionType, question: String
    let answers: [String]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case questionID = "question_id"
        case questionType = "question_type"
        case question, answers
    }
}
```

I don't think your model is wrong in anyway. But try this code to make sure:

```
let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(QuestionResult.self, from: data)
print(result?.questions[1].answers)
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue, please explain your answer. Why are you adding properties that OP clearly is not interested in?

Comment: I have explained it just now.

Comment: Weird, the answer is the same as the question and yet it gets accepted. Well, well...

Comment: We all went through a situation where the solution was right in front of us and so obvious but we couldn't figure it out. Every little bit helps.